# Is it possible to create a docker image from a yocto generated image?

Tags: docker, yocto

I want to use yocto to build a customized image for an embedded system and I want to create a docker image from this custom image. Usually in docker one would build a image using a parent image e.g. `FROM ubuntu:xenial`. However, in this case there is no official image available, so I need to create a new base image. I looked up the [docs for creating a base image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/) but it doesn't explain the whole process. I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint or a link for a tutorial or something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. A dockerfile would look like that:

```
FROM scratch
ADD app-container-image-python3-data-collector-container-x86-64.tar.bz2 /
```

But I would recommend having a look at [meta-virtualization](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-virtualization/) and oci-images, which you can generate directly and e.g. upload to docker.io.